# button onpress not working with own component

Tags: react-native, expo

I have made a button component and want to add a onpress but it doesnt work. Can anyone explain me why its not working ?

Button Component.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const Button = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
};

export default Button;
```

Main.js

```
...
<Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Jetzt registrieren"/>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to extract you onPress prop

```
const Button = ({ title,onPress }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
};
```